# Regular expression: reference to matching result count from pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I am editing large html file and it is necessary to insert `<span id="%d"></span>` (where `%d` is the number of match) into the `<p></p>` tags.

**Sample Input:**

```
<p>stack</p>
<p>overflow</p>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<p><span class="class" id="f=1">stack</p>
<p><span class="class" id="f=2">overflow</p>
```

To match the `<p></p>` I use the following regular expression to match results:
`<p>(.*?)<\/p>`

Afterwards, matches are substituted with:
`<p><span class="class" id="f=???">$1</span></p>`

Is it available reference to the number of match from pattern? ("f=???")

Comment: Use a language specific means.

Comment: added `javascript` tag

Comment: Use a callback inside `.replace`, add a counter there.

Comment: It is not possible to refer to the number of replacements from within the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to parse HTML using regex :

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

[Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

---

Instead, generate a DOM element with the content and update the `p` tags.

```js
var str = `<p>stack</p>
<p>overflow</p>`;

// generate a temporary div element
var temp = document.createElement('div');
// set html content
temp.innerHTML = str;

// get all p tags and convert into array
// for older browser use [].slice.call(.....)
Array.from(temp.querySelectorAll('p'))
  // iterate over the elements
  .forEach(function(ele, i) {
    //  update the content
    ele.innerHTML = '<span class="class" id="f=' + (i + 1) + '">' + ele.innerHTML + '</span>';
  });

// get the html content
console.log(temp.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 2):

RegEx can't count matches, so you'd have to do that part in JavaScript.

```js
var input = "<p>stack</p>\n<p>overflow</p>"

const regex = /<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g;

var count = 0;
var result = input.replace(regex, function(match, contents) {
    ++count;
    return '<p><span class="class" id="f=' + count + '">' + contents + '</span></p>';
});

console.log(result);
```

`console.log(result)` would yield:

```
<p><span class="class" id="f=1">stack</span></p>
<p><span class="class" id="f=2">overflow</span></p>
```